# Lightning Component change endDate from startDate automatically

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component with start date and end date and i want to achieve exactly the same behavior as in the New/Edit event. So, my purpose is whenever the user changes the start date, i want the end date to be (start date + 1 hour). But i cannot find a way to achieve this. Any ideas?
Code below: My problem is in the function handleStartChange of controller js
Component

```
<!-- 2020-05-12 @ggalaios This Lightning Component handles the Start Date and End Date as well as Is All Day Event on event record-->

<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" 
                access="global" >

    <!-- Define Attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="inputType" type="String" default="datetime"/> <!-- set dynamically the type of the input -->
    <aura:attribute name="startDatetime" type="Date" />
    <aura:attribute name="endDatetime" type="Date" />
    <aura:attribute name="isAllDayEvent" type="Boolean" Default="false" />
    <!-- Handlers Declaration -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <lightning:input type="{!v.inputType}" name="startDateTime" value="{!v.startDatetime}"
                     label="{!$Label.c.Start}" onchange="{!c.handleStartChange}" required="true"/>
    <lightning:input type="{!v.inputType}" name="endDateTime" value="{!v.endDatetime}"
                     label="{!$Label.c.End}" onchange="{!c.handleEndChange}" required="true"/>

    <lightning:input type="toggle" label="{!$Label.c.All_Day_Event}" name="allDayEvent" checked="{!v.isAllDayEvent}"
                     onchange="{!c.allDayEventHandle}"
                     message-toggle-active="{!$Label.c.Yes}"
                     message-toggle-inactive="{!$Label.c.Yes}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(component.get("v.isAllDayEvent"));
        var startDate = new Date();
        startDate.getMinutes() && startDate.setMinutes(60);
        component.set("v.startDatetime", startDate.toISOString());
        console.log(startDate.toISOString());
        var finalDate = new Date();
        finalDate.getMinutes() && finalDate.setMinutes(120);
        component.set("v.endDatetime", finalDate.toISOString());
    },

    handleStartChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('handled');
        console.log(component.get("v.startDatetime"));
        console.log(component.get("v.endDatetime"));
        var start = component.get("v.startDatetime");
        console.log(start);
        start.getMinutes() && start.setMinutes(60);
        console.log('dgfdhgfdf');
        component.set("v.endDatetime", start.toISOString());
        console.log('emd');
    },

    handleEndChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('handled');
        console.log(component.get("v.startDatetime"));
        console.log(component.get("v.endDatetime"));
    },

    allDayEventHandle: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('handled@!@');
        console.log(component.get("v.isAllDayEvent"));
        if(component.get("v.isAllDayEvent")) {
            component.set("v.inputType", "date")
        } else {
            component.set("v.inputType", "datetime")
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to first convert it into date and then set the minutes the following works fine for me

```
var start = component.get("v.startDatetime");
var d = new Date(start);
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() +60);
component.set("v.endDatetime", d.toISOString());
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much!